# What is this error - > APIConnectionError: Connection error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, openai-api, streamlit

I am trying to use Streamlit in Snowflake to connect to OpenAI.

```
`import openai
client = openai.OpenAI(api_key='SECRETKEY')

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "hello world - what is the answer to the universe and all the rest?"
    }
  ],
  temperature=1,
  max_tokens=256,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0
)
print(response)`
```

However, I gotten this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCsyj.png)

The Error I got as follows

```
`File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/udf/5208951221/streamlit_app.py", line 13, in <module>
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_utils/_utils.py", line 301, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/resources/chat/completions.py", line 598, in create
    return self._post(
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1063, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 842, in request
    return self._request(
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 898, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 933, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 898, in _request
    return self._retry_request(
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 933, in _retry_request
    return self._request(
File "/usr/lib/python_udf/b4b5fcefd7dd2d7996a3b2a1d0a7ffb199edf4f928b67977b49d2acb22540ece/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 905, in _request
    raise APIConnectionError(request=request) from err`
```

I am not sure how to goggle for this solution as there is no specific error but just Connection Error.
Anyone able to me on this?

using OpenAI version 1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/python-library-error-types), the error could be caused by your **network settings, proxy configuration, SSL certificates, or firewall rules**:

| TYPE | OVERVIEW |
| --- | --- |
| APIConnectionError | **Cause:** Issue connecting to our services. **Solution:** Check your network settings, proxy configuration, SSL certificates, or firewall rules. |